# Is there a time where the link of a subset is not equal to the boundary of its star?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I'm just learning about simplicial complexes and have been looking at diagrams that conceptualize the closure, star and link of a vertex. In all the cases I saw, the link is the boundary of the star. Is that always true?

Edit:

> $\begin{multline} \text{A subcomplex is a simplicial complex L \subseteq K.} \\ 
> Cl(L) = \{ \tau \in K |\tau \leq \sigma \in L\}. \\
> St(L) = \{\sigma \in K | \sigma \geq \tau \in L\}. \\
> Lk(L) = Cl(St(L)) - St(Cl(L) - \{\emptyset\}). \\~ \end{multline}$

Comment: What do you mean by "boundary"?

Comment: Added definitions

Comment: You still have not defined "boundary"...